# AS3/Flex : Interface extends interface

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

In AS3/Flex, is it possible for me that one interface extends another interface ?

I have created interface A. Now I want to create another Interface B which extends interface A.

I google a lot but couldnt find any convincing answer. Please help.

Comment: Interfaces aren't extended; they are implemented.  So an interface can "implement" another interface just like a class can.

Comment: Correct. I was just going through few theoretical questions I read on a blog. I thought let me ask you guys if anybody knows if its achievable in AS3. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: What blog?  Are we doing your homework for you?

Comment: @Reboog711: Can't understand what you mean with `an interface can "implement" another interface`.

Comment: I'll post a formal answer; I suppose.  But, it looks like @splash is 90% of the way there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can extend an [interface](http://livedocs.adobe.com/specs/actionscript/3/as3_specification95.html):

> Multiple interfaces can be inherited by another interface through the
>   extends clause or by a class through the implements clause. Instances
>   of a class that implements an interface be long to the type
>   represented by the interface. Interface definitions must only contain
>   function definitions, which may include get and set methods.

Keep in mind: Sometimes it is faster to just try it out or simply look in the Flex SDK source code. ;-)

`${FLEX_HOME}\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\IUIComponent.as`:

```
package mx.core
{ 
...
public interface IUIComponent extends IFlexDisplayObject
{
...
```

Comment: This is correct. You can have a problems with extending interfaces only if you set get-er and set-er of one member in different interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

In my comment I said Interfaces aren't extended; they are implemented.  That should have been that interfaces are implemented by classes using the implement keyword.  When you want a single interface to 'extend' multiple interfaces, just use the extends keyword and separate them by commas.

Take this interface, IMyFirstInterface:

```
public interface IMyFirstInterface {
 // method definitions here
}
```

And then take, this other interface, IMySecondInterface:

```
public interface IMySecondInterface {
 // method definitions here
}
```

Both are "Stand alone" meaning they don't have any relation to another interface.  But, a third interface can extend them both, like this:

```
public interface IMyThirdInterface extends IMyFirstInterface, IMySecondInterface{
 // method definitions here
}
```

Your class will implement the Interface, like this:

```
public class myClass implements IMyThirdInterface{
 // other class stuff
}
```

myClass is required to include all the methods defined in iMyThirdInterface, IMyFirstInterface, and iMySecondInterface because it implements IMyThirdInterface which extends IMyFirstInterface and IMySecondInterface.

Off the top of my head; I have no idea how "collisions" are handled.  If IMyFirstInterface and IMySecondInterface implement the same method with different signatures I would expect a compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces can extend other interfaces.
Classes can extend classes.
See the correlation here?
Its like lego.

Interfaces implement classes.
Classes implement interfaces.
It should make sense now.